# How can I say "Available in Chinese" about a product

Tags: translation

I'm making a marketing image for a product, and the logo is in English. I want to add in Simplified Chinese under the logo the sentence "Available in Chinese" so that people who see it understand that the product itself has a Chinese version.

I found the following options but am unsure which is best for this scenario, or if any are good at all:

- 可用中文
- 在中国语文
- 用中文（表达

Comment: What kind of product?

Comment: It's a video game

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, 支持中文 (literally "supports Chinese) is the most idiomatic way afaik. (I read Chinese game websites every day.)  有中文 (literally "has Chinese) is another casual way. Unlike the other answer states, you need to use a verb here in Chinese. (Actually it is English that does not use a verb here: English uses the adjective "available")

中文版本, or 中文版, means "Chinese version". If you have a link that points to the Chinese version, you can use the phrase as the link text.

Answer (score 2):

You could translate directly by 中文版本.

What we in English or French must express by grammatical words or expressions is in Chinese often omitted and inferred from the context.

Comment: For instance, if you add an existantial or modal verbs like 有 or 可, it would sound redundant

Answer (score 0):

支持中文 -- The most appropriate phrase.

中文可还行  -- Internet slang: Is Chinese OK?

中文不香吗 -- Internet slang: Is Chinese good?

The usages of that slang are subtle,  they are rhetorical questions, usually used when people want to say: It is good, isn't it? Don't you want it?

If you want to add some humor, you can use those phrases, totally acceptable to all people.